# Android: Cannot use AppCompat theme with custom window title

Tags: android, android-appcompat, android-mvvm, custom-titlebar

I'm like in a kind of a vicious circle. I'm trying to implement MVVM pattern into my app, but to instantiate ViewModel the next way:

```
ViewModel loginViewModel = new ViewModelProvider(this).get(LoginViewModel.class);
```

it's necessary to extend AppCompat, but when I extend AppCompatActivity in my BaseActivity class I get an exception of type:

```
"You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity"
```

And the problem is I cannot use AppCompat theme in manifest because I'm already using

```
android:theme="@style/Theme.myTheme.TitleBar"
```

TitleBar:

```
<resources>
  <!--parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat"-->
  <style name="Theme.myTheme.TitleBar" parent="android:Theme">
    <item name="android:windowTitleSize">50dip</item>
  </style>
</resources>
```

and then I configure the ActionBar in code and then in BaseActivity:

```
requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE);
```

So I don't know how to combine extending AppCompatActivity with custom title feature.

Edit 1: In reply to @CommonsWare

If I set

```
android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar"
```

in my Manifest file then I get thenext exception:

```
"You cannot combine custom titles with other title features"
```

as soon as the app starts, in the first line of the next piece of code which creates the drawer menu container:

```
// HACK: "steal" the first child of decor view
ViewGroup decor = (ViewGroup) ((Activity)context).getWindow().getDecorView();
View child = decor.getChildAt(0);
decor.removeView(child);
FrameLayout container = drawer.findViewById(R.id.container); // This is the container we defined just now.
container.addView(child);
```

So I guess no luck yet :(

Comment: What use is the `android:Theme` for you?

Comment: Why not use `Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar` as the base theme? "it's necessary to extend AppCompat" -- to use `ViewModel`, I believe it is only necessary to extend `ComponentActivity`, not `AppCompatActivity` (which itself extends from `ComponentActivity`).

Comment: Thanks @CommonsWare, I tried your suggestion and edited my question in reply. Please take a look at it.

Comment: Thanks for your reply @gtxtreme. Not totally sure why I need android:theme, but the fact it it won't compile without setting a parent for the style, and if I set something different from android:theme I have the "You cannot combine custom titles with other title features" error.